# Erro ao retornar mensagens de validação com o Form Request no Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Olá, pessoal! Estou tentando retornar mensagens de validações personalizadas com o Form Request do Laravel, já coloquei as validações dentro de "public function rules()", e as mensagens personalizadas dentro de "public function messages()", porém as mensagens não são retornadas, conseguem me ajudar?
OBS: O formulário possui alguns campos gerado por um FOR, quando retiro esses campos, as mensagens são exibidas. 
IMPORTANTE: Esses campos gerado pelo FOR não estão sendo validados no Form Request, não inclui eles na validação. 
ERRO NO CONSOLE: No console é apresentada a seguinte mensagem: set-Cookie header is ignored in response from url 127.0.0.1:8000 Cookie length should be less than or equal to 4096 characters.

```
// VIEW ONDE SE ENCONTRA O FORMULÁRIO

@section('conteudo')

<section class="content-header">
    <h3>Cadastrar registro:</h3>
// CÓDIGO PARA EXIBIR MENSAGENS DE VALIDAÇÃO
    @if(isset($errors) && count($errors) > 0)
        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
            {{$error}}
        @endforeach
    @endif

</section>

<section class="content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <!-- Horizontal Form -->
            <div class="box box-info">                 
                <div class="box-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <form action="{{ route('contestacao.create') }}" autocomplete="off" class="form-horizontal" name="cadastrar-tabulacao" id="cadastrar-tabulacao" method="POST">  
                            @csrf  
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" id="notificacao-sucesso" style="display:none">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                    <h4><i class="icon fa fa-check"></i> Notificação!</h4>
                                    O documento foi cadastro com sucesso.
                                </div>
                                <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" id="notificacao-erro" style="display:none">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                    <h4><i class="icon fa fa-ban"></i> Notificação!</h4>
                                    Erro ao cadastrar o registro.
                                </div> 
                                <h4>Dados do cliente:</h4>
                                <div class="form-group">    
                                    <div class="col-sm-8">                            
                                    <label for="nome_cliente">Nome do cliente: <span class="text-red"> *</span></label>
                                        <input type="text" minlength="5" maxlength="120" class="form-control required" name="nome_cliente" id="nome_cliente" placeholder="Digite o nome do cliente" >
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">    
                                    <div class="col-sm-4">                            
                                    <label for="documento">Documento: <span class="text-red"> *</span></label>
                                        <input type="text" minlength="11" maxlength="14" class="form-control required" name="documento" id="documento" placeholder="CPF ou CNPJ" >
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-4">                            
                                    <label for="instancia">Instância:</label>
                                        <input type="text" minlength="10" maxlength="10" class="form-control required" name="instancia" id="instancia" placeholder="Digite a instância">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-4">                            
                                    <label for="pcobranca">Conta cobrança: <span class="text-red"> *</span></label>
                                        <input type="text" minlength="12" maxlength="14" class="form-control required" name="pcobranca" id="pcobranca" placeholder="Digite o perfil de cobrança" >
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <h4>Dados do ajuste:</h4>
                                <div class="form-group">    
                                    <div class="col-sm-6">                            
                                        <label for="motivo">Motivo: <span class="text-red"> *</span></label>
                                        <select class="form-control select2 required" id="motivo" name="motivo" style="width: 100%;" >
                                            <option value="">Escolha uma opção</option>
                                            <option>Acionamento Indevido</option>
                                            <option>Atraso Na Mudança De Endereço</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-6">                            
                                        <label for="tipocontest">Tipo Contestação: <span class="text-red"> *</span></label>
                                        <select class="form-control required" id="tipocontest" name="tipocontest" >
                                            <option value="">Escolha uma opção</option>
                                            <option>Ajuste</option>
                                            <option>Acordo</option>
                                        </select>   
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="my-form-group">
                                    <div class="my-table-itens-title" style="width: calc(100% - 17px)">
                                        <div class="my-form-control my-title col-sm-2" style="font-size: 22px;"><span class="fa fa-arrow-circle-down"></span></div>
                                        <div class="my-form-control my-title col-sm-2">Venc Fatura</div>
                                        <div class="my-form-control my-title col-sm-2">Valor fatura</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="my-table-itens">
                                        @php ($number_itens = 13)
                                        @for ($i = 0; $i < $number_itens; $i++)
                                            <div class="my-form-group">
                                                <div class="my-form-control col-sm-2" style="background-color: #e6ebef;">{{ $i + 1 }}</div>                                        
                                                <input type="text" name="vencimento_fatura[]" class="my-form-control col-sm-2 datepicker" minlength="8" >
                                                <input type="text" name="valor_fatura[]"  class="my-form-control col-sm-2 valor-contestacao" minlength="3" >
                                                <input type="text" name="valor_solicitado[]"  class="my-form-control col-sm-2 valor-contestacao" minlength="3" >
                                                <input type="text" name="valor_contestado[]"  class="my-form-control col-sm-2 valor-contestacao" minlength="3" >
                                                <select type="text" name="tipo_correcao[]" class="my-form-control col-sm-2" >
                                                    <option value="">----</option>
                                                    <option>Boleto</option>
                                                    <option>Conta Futura</option>
                                                    <option>Reembolso</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                        @endfor
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <input type="hidden" name="number_itens" value="{{ $number_itens }}">
                                <h4>Dados de Causa Raiz:</h4>
                                <div class="form-group">    
                                    <div class="col-sm-4">                            
                                        <label for="causa_raiz">Causa Raiz: <span class="text-red"> *</span></label>
                                        <select id="causa_raiz" name="causa_raiz" class="form-control select2 required" style="width: 100%;" >
                                            <option value="">Escolha uma opção</option>
                                            <option>Sem necessidade de correção</option>
                                            <option>Acionamento Indevido</option>
                                            <option>Atribuir Exceção</option>
                                            <option>Atribuir REQ</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-4">                            
                                        <label for="correcao_realizada">Correção Realizada: <span class="text-red"> *</span></label>
                                        <select id="correcao_realizada" name="correcao_realizada" class="form-control required">
                                            <option value="">Escolha uma opção</option>
                                            <option>Sim</option>
                                            <option>Não</option>
                                            <option>N/A</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <h4>Fechamento da Solicitação:</h4>
                                <div class="form-group">    
                                    <div class="col-sm-4">                            
                                    <label for="matricula_primeiro_nivel">Colaborador 1º nível:</label>
                                        <input id="matricula_primeiro_nivel" minlength="5" maxlength="15" name="matricula_primeiro_nivel" type="text" class="form-control required" placeholder="Matrícula completa">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-4">                            
                                    <label for="fechamento_analise">Fechamento da análise: <span class="text-red"> *</span></label>
                                        <select id="fechamento_analise" name="fechamento_analise" class="form-control required" >
                                            <option value="">Escolha uma opção</option>
                                            <option>Procedente</option>
                                            <option>Procedente Parcial</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-sm-12"> 
                                    <label for="anotacoes">Anotações: <span class="text-red"> *</span></label>
                                        <textarea form="cadastrar-tabulacao" id="anotacoes" name="anotacoes" class="form-control required" rows="5"></textarea>
                                        {{-- <textarea form="cadastrar-tabulacao" name="anotacoes2" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea> --}}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- /.box-body -->
                                <div class="box-footer">
                                    <button type="reset" id="limpar_formulario" class="btn btn-danger">Limpar</button>
                                    <button type="submit" id="cadastrar_contestacao" class="btn btn-success pull-right" onclick="return confirm('Tem certeza que deseja cadastrar o registro?')">Cadastrar Contestação</button>
                                </div>
                                <!-- /.box-footer -->
                            </div>
                        </form>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <h4>Suas tratativas:</h4>
                            <div class="small-box bg-green">
                                <div class="inner">
                                    <p>Registros realizados hoje:</p>
                                    <h3 id="registros-hoje">50</h3>
                                </div>
                                <div class="icon">
                                    <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i>
                                </div>
                                <a href="meus_registros" class="small-box-footer">
                                Ver meu histórico geral <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="small-box bg-yellow">
                                <div class="inner">
                                    <p>Registros pendentes, sem solução:</p>
                                    <h3 id="registros-abertos">30</h3>
                                </div>
                                <div class="icon">
                                    <i class="fa fa-folder-open-o"></i>
                                </div>
                                <a href="registros_pendentes" class="small-box-footer">
                                Ver meus registros sem solução <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <div class="form-group">    
                                    <form name="queda_chamada" id="queda_chamada" method="post">
                                        @csrf                            
                                        <label for="documento" style="font-weight: 400;">Use o botão abaixo para registrar uma queda de ligação.</label>
                                        <div class="box-footer">
                                            <button type="submit" id="registrar_queda" class="btn btn-block btn-danger" onclick="return confirm('Tem certeza que deseja registrar ligação caiu?')"><span class="fa fa-phone"></span> Registrar queda de chamada</button>
                                        </div> 
                                    </form>
                                </div> 
                            </div>
                            <h4>Cálcular período (n° dias):</h4>
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <div class="box-body">
                                    <div class="form-group">  
                                        <div class="col-sm-6">                            
                                        <label for="data-inicio">Data inicial: <span class="text-red"> *</span></label>
                                            <input type="text" id="data-inicio" minlength="10" maxlength="10" class="form-control datepicker" >
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-6">                            
                                        <label for="data-fim">Data final: <span class="text-red"> *</span></label>
                                            <input type="text" id="data-fim" minlength="10" maxlength="10" class="form-control datepicker" >
                                        </div>                                   
                                    </div> 
                                </div> 
                                <div class="box-footer">
                                    <button type="button" id="btn-calcular-periodo" class="btn btn-block btn-success"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> Calcular período</button>
                                </div>
                                <div>Número de dias no intervalo selecionado: <b id="numero-dias"></b></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>                
            </div>
            <!-- /.box -->
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
@endsection

// CONTROLLER CRIADO

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\MesaRequest;

class MesaController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function contestacao_index()
    {
        return view('services.inicio');

    }

    public function contestacao_create(MesaRequest $request)
    {
         // NÃO INSERI NADA AINDA, ESTOU APENAS TESTANDO AS VALIDAÇÕES      
    }

}


// REQUEST CRIADO PARA DEFINIR AS VALIDAÇÕES E MENSAGENS

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class MesaRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'nome_cliente' => 'required',
            'documento' => 'required',
            'pcobranca' => 'required',
            'motivo' => 'required',
            'tipocontest' => 'required',
            'anotacoes' => 'required',                         
            'fechamento_analise' => 'required', 
            'correcao_realizada' => 'required',                       
        ];
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'nome_cliente.required' => 'O campo "Nome do cliente" é obrigatório!',
            'documento.required' => 'O campo "Nome do cliente" é obrigatório!',
            'pcobranca.required' => 'O campo "Conta cobrança" é obrigatório!',
            'motivo.required' => 'O campo "Motivo" é obrigatório!',
            'tipocontest.required' => 'O campo "Tipo Contestação" é obrigatório!',
            'anotacoes.required' => 'O campo "Anotações" é obrigatório!', 
            'fechamento_analise.required' => 'O campo "Fechamento" é obrigatório!', 
            'correcao_realizada.required' => 'O campo "Correçao" é obrigatório!', 
        ];        
    }
}
```

Comment: pode acontecer de algum, input estar incorreto, verifique os inputs, verifique os fillables, exponha seu problema com mais detalhes.

Comment: @AndréMartins, vi que quando o erro acontece, no console é gerada a seguinte mensagem: set-Cookie header is ignored in response from url 127.0.0.1:8000 Cookie length should be less than or equal to 4096 characters. O formulário que criei tem muitos campos, fiz um teste e diminuí a quantidade de campos e o problema não ocorreu... Acredito que algo está limitando a quantidade de campos do formulário.

Comment: dá uma olhada nesse link: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#a-note-on-optional-fields

Comment: Coloque a View e o Controller na pergunta

Comment: Olá tudo bem? Os inputs são do  tipo array? Ou são mais de 6 inputs com name diferentes? Pois não existe essa limitação de 6 campos required em um request. Eu utilizo com vários e não dá erro algum. Um exemplo próximo do que você está fazendo tenho em meu github neste [link](https://github.com/luiz-justino/websystem) (o request está dentro do [controller](https://github.com/luiz-justino/websystem/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/ClienteController.php) e a [view](https://github.com/luiz-justino/websystem/blob/master/resources/views/novoCliente.blade.php)).

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Coloquei a view, o controller e request na pergunta para explicar melhor, interessante que quando comento a linha "\App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class" dentro do arquivo "App\Http\kernel.php", o problema deixa de ocorrer.

Comment: @LuizFernando, na verdade, o formulário possui vários campos e estou validando apenas alguns.
Quando diminuo a quantidade de campos, o problema deixa de ocorrer e as mensagens são exibidas.

Comment: Deve ser configuração errada qua do chegará em casa crio uma resposta

Comment: A questão é que quando seu input é um array ou seja <input name='documento[]>' no rules você deve especificar: 'documento.*' => 'required' e no messages: `'documento.*.required' => 'Um documento é obrigatório',` . Como você tem inputs simples e inputs que são um array, como você não fez isso para os inputs com array ele não está exibindo corretamente. Quando se coloca * ele se refere a todos os elementos com name do input que você especificou, no meu exemplo, 'documento'.

Comment: @LuizFernando, tirei do tipo array e coloquei o nome do input  concatenado com a variável $i, exemplo: name="vencimento_fatura{{ $i + 1 }}", porém o erro ainda persiste, o que intriga é que os campos gerados dentro desse "For" não estão sendo validados. Quando removo os campos gerados pelo "For" o problema deixa de existir. De alguma forma os campos gerados pelo "For" estão causando o problema.

Comment: Esse jeito usando o for e um contador é outro jeito de validar inputs que são do tipo array, é um jeito mais trabalhoso. Eu prefiro usar o campo.* que o * significa que ele irá aplicar a todos os campos que tem o name campo. Tente usar com o "*" para ver se o problema não ocorre. Pois eu antes de descobrir como usar validação em inputs do tipo array ele deu a mesma coisa que o seu está dando.

Comment: @LuizFernando, estranho é que se comento a função "messages" do request, o problema deixa de existir e as mensagens são exibidas em inglês. Vale ressaltar que os campos gerados pelo For não estão sendo validados dentro do request, eu não inclui eles na validação.

Comment: Entendi, tenta executar esse comando para exibir as mensagens e vê o que ocorre e me fala aqui:  `@if($errors->any())
    @foreach($errors->all() as $erro)
        {{$erro}}
    @endforeach
@endif`

Comment: @LuizFernando, fiz isso e o problema persiste, as mensagens não são apresentadas. O console continua apresentando a mensagem: set-Cookie header is ignored in response from url http://127.0.0.1:8000/ Cookie length should be less than or equal to 4096 characters. De alguma forma, os campos gerados pelo input, mesmo não sendo validados, estão causando algum conflito para personalizar as mensagens.

Comment: Vi que o problema deixa de existir quando tento UMA dessas duas coisas: 
1. quando comento a função "messages" do request mesmo deixando os inputs gerados pelo for, as mensagens são apresentadas em inglês.
2. quando removo os campos gerados pelo for, as mensagens personalizadas funcionam perfeitamente.

Comment: Bem eu não entendo tão bem como funciona esse  Encrypting Cookie, mas o que ele está informando é que ele tem um limite de 4096 caracteres para o cookie. No for que você utiliza para elementos dentro de my-table-iten, você não está adicionando um id para cada um o que é interessante pois cada input é um elemento diferente, pode ser que como vc não especificou id ele está guardando todos de mesmo nome num mesmo cookie e gerando o erro. É uma teoria, tenta adicionar os ids. Comentar o messages não é uma boa ideia.

Comment: Se quiser comentar o messages deixando as mensagens automáticas, você vai ter que traduzir os retornos para português e aí você faz isso: https://github.com/lucascudo/laravel-pt-BR-localization .

Comment: coloquei com id, porém o problema persiste kkk já tentei de tudo, nunca vi um problema como esse. valeu pela dica do pt-BR.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi o problema mudando a versão do Laravel, estava usando a 6.x. Mudei o projeto para a versão 5.8 e o problema deixou de ocorrer.